# How to deploy .ipynb files on server?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, deployment, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I'm a bit confused.
want to deploy a flask web app, which has been written in Jupyter lab.
want to know how can ipynb file be deployed.
thanks.

Comment: You probably want to learn about viola for jupyter https://voila.readthedocs.io/ or nbviewer https://github.com/jupyter/nbviewer depending on how much interactivity you desire. In any case this question looks to vague and you should provide more details

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am using PyWebIO for developing web app.
but writing it in Jupyter Lab. Wanted to know if there is any possibilities to deploy the web app without converting .ipynb to .py?
very interesting libraries though.
Link to [PyWebIO](https://github.com/wang0618/PyWebIO)